# Zeppelin: How to see text results from JDBC query

Tags: apache-zeppelin

On SQL queries `zeppelin` 0.8.1 provide table output and several visualizations of data out of the box:
[image]

And it is very useful most of the time.

But sometimes I want just select text for presentation.

Said for query `SELECT version();`. There table output is annoying:
[image]

What very interesting, there already implemented text output, for example for EXPLAIN:

[image]

Off course ideally for `EXPLAIN` query you may also expect more visualize for nods, cost and so on, but it is absolutely another question.

So, main question: **How I can switch output to text form for some of my `SQL` queries except `explain` but in similar form?**

Additionally, If I run some maintenance commands like VACUUM and ANALYZE I can see output in many IDE, but in zeppelin it is empty!

[image: ANALYZE VERBOSE test_origin_h;]

Answer (score 1):

```sql
/*'EXPLAIN '*/ select version();
```

An ugly workaround can be used while JDBCInterpreter contains [EXPLAIN_PREDICATE](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/97c845a6f39e60d93a553d9b438bb11fb38e0497/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/jdbc/JDBCInterpreter.java#L754)

```java
  private static final String EXPLAIN_PREDICATE = "EXPLAIN ";
              String results = getResults(resultSet,
                  !containsIgnoreCase(sqlToExecute, EXPLAIN_PREDICATE), isComplete);
```

In future it's will be nice to manage output type via paragraph properties.

VACUUM and ANALYZE send messages which should be caught via [Statement#getWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings())

Comment: Nice workaround for first part. `/*EXPLAIN */ select version();` indeed works.

But `/*EXPLAIN */ ANALYZE VERBOSE test_origin_h;` still prints only "Query executed successfully. Affected rows : 0".

I upvote your ansver, but it is partial answer.

Comment: As I understand messages from `analyze verbose` can be catched with getWarnings. This functionality isn't implemented yes.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getWarnings()

Comment: Then I should fill feature request to zeppelin? Please update your answer and I accept it.

Comment: @Hubbitus, you could create new JIRA issue. Zeppelin is project in Apache Foundation. The core development team is absent. Perhaps somebody will implement this functionality.